# Fetch excel file name information with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Main Folder` and there are multiple `sub-folder` in it.
For example: The Main Folder names **MAIN**.
             In the **MAIN**, there are `sub-folder` called **sub1**, **sub2**, **sub3**, **sub4**.....
In `sub-folder`, there are many excels in it (Too many, do not know accurate number)
I use VBA to get file name in **MAIN**.

Here is my first try:

```
Sub Get_MAIN_File_Names()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect, xFname

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .Title = "Select Main File"
   .Show

   'LOCATES FILES
   If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
      xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
      xFname = Dir(xDirect)

      'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
      Do While xFname <> ""

        'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME
         DrawingNumb = xFname
         RevNumb = xFname

        'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
         ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = DrawingNumb
         ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = RevNumb
         xFname = Dir()
         xRow = xRow + 1
      Loop

   End If
End With
End Sub
```

However, my VBA code is incorrect.
For this code, I need to select `sub-folder` to get the excels name.
How can I do to just select `Main Folder` and get all excels name in it?
Moreover, I also want to get the excels' **modified time**.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Search for "recursive folder search", many examples and code snippets in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+recursive+folder+search+

Comment: and have a look at the `FileSystemObject`. Its easier for looping and gives you direct access to modified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime under Tools->Reference in your VBA editor.

FileSystemObject is your friend here. Try the following alteration to your code above:

```
Option Explicit

Private xRow As Long

Sub Get_MAIN_File_Names()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim xDirect As String
    Dim xRootFolder As Folder
    Dim DrawingNumb As String
    Dim RevNumb As String
    Dim rootFolderStr As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    xRow = 0
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .Title = "Select Main File"
       .Show

       'PROCESS ROOT FOLDER
       If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
          xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
          Set xRootFolder = fso.GetFolder(xDirect)
          ProcessFolder fso, xRootFolder
       End If

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolder(fso As FileSystemObject, xFolder As Folder)
    Dim xFiles As files
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim xSubFolders As Folders
    Dim xSubFolder As Folder
    Dim DrawingNumb As String
    Dim RevNumb As String

    Set xFiles = xFolder.files

    'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
    For Each xFile In xFiles

      'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME
       DrawingNumb = xFile.Name
       RevNumb = xFile.Name

      'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = DrawingNumb
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = RevNumb
       xRow = xRow + 1
    Next xFile

    Set xSubFolders = xFolder.SubFolders
    For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
        ProcessFolder fso, xSubFolder
    Next xSubFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Great. It works. Could you please explain more detail to the code? I'm new in excel VBA. Thanks!

Comment: In Get_MAIN_File_Names(), it prompts the user for the root folder. from there, it calls the first iteration of ProcessFolder on the root folder. ProcessFolder does two things - 1) collects/writes all filenames in that folders and 2) calls ProcessFolder again on each subfolder. In programming, this technique of calling the same function is called recursion.

Comment: If I want to add subfolders name in excel `column A` and `column B` shows files name, what code should I add?

Answer (score 1):

For code to work, set reference to the following library: `Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

```
Private r As Long

Sub IterateOverFiles()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Call ProcessFolder(fso.GetFolder("C:\Main\"))
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(fld As Folder)
    Dim fl As File
    Dim subFld As Folder
    For Each fl In fld.Files
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, "A") = fl.Name 'File name
        Cells(r, "B") = fl.Size 'File size
    Next
    For Each subFld In fld.SubFolders
        Call ProcessFolder(subFld)
    Next
End Sub
```